# Why JQuery on click is showing only the first element of the class?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch the current value on click. But it's returning the first element of the class only.

```
$(".list-country").on("click",function(){
        var country = $(".list-country span").html();
      loadState("stateData", country);
    })
```

Comment: This is [the documented behavior](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html). What are you expecting to get? An array of strings?

Comment: try the following `$(this).find("span").html()`

Comment: Hi @Teemu, Thanks for the reply. For example, There are 5 links with class name "list-country". I want to show when user will click on first item it will save the first item value to the variable country. If click 2nd then save 2nd value to the variable country. So on ...

Comment: Also if you show your HTML, perhaps we can give you a better script - You likely want to investigate "closest"

Comment: Hello @CarstenLøvboAndersen, thanks my friend. It works.